# When I click the button it adds £3.00 to the total on top of what is correct

Tags: c#

The program is for a pizza menu, the button I click to add the pizza adds £3.00 on top of the actual total, I have looked for errors but can not find the problem. The program is not fully finished, only the adding of the pizza total is complete but something is wrong with the code which I can not find.
I also would like any suggestion to make the program more efficient.

```
    string stuffedcrust;
    string Deeppan;
    string thincrispy;

    private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                                                                                //Add type of crust to summary box
        stuffedcrust = rbStuffedcrust.Text;
        SummaryBox.Text = stuffedcrust;
    }
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    private int clickCounter = 0;

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // Button to add the value pf the pizza to the text box
    {
        this.clickCounter++;
        if (this.clickCounter < 10)                         // number of time the button can be pressed to add Pizzas
        {
            radioButton1.Checked = false;
            radioButton2.Checked = false;
            radioButton3.Checked = false;
            radioButton4.Checked = false;
            radioButton6.Checked = false;
            radioButton7.Checked = false;
            rbThinandcrispy.Checked = false;
            rbStuffedcrust.Checked = false;
            rbDeeppan.Checked = false;
            checkBoxCrispyOnions.Checked = false;
            checkBoxExtraCheese.Checked = false;
            checkBoxPeppers.Checked = false;
            checkBoxPepperoni.Checked = false;
            checkBoxGarlicSauce.Checked = false;
            checkBox12.Checked = false;

            /*StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(SummaryBox.Text, true);

            sw.WriteLine();
            sw.WriteLine();
            sw.WriteLine();
            sw.WriteLine();
            sw.Close(); */

            MessageBox.Show("Pizza Added");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No more Pizza's can be added, the maximum order is 10");

        }
    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        File.Create(textBox1.Text).Close();
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
        of.ShowDialog();
        textBox1.Text = of.FileName;
    }

    public double PizzaPrice { get; set; }                                  //Global Public
    double ExtraTopping;                                                    //Global

    private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string CT;

        if (radioButton2.Enabled == true)                                   //PIZZA CHEESE TOMATO
        {
            double ctp = 3.50;
            PizzaPrice += ctp;
            txtPizzaPrice.Text = "£ " + PizzaPrice.ToString();
            CT = radioButton2.Text;
            SummaryBox.Text = CT;
        }
        else
        {
            SummaryBox.Clear();
        }

    }

    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string VS;

        if (radioButton1.Enabled == true)                                   //PIZZA Veg SUpreme
        {
            double vsp = 5.20;
            PizzaPrice += vsp;
            txtPizzaPrice.Text = "£ " + PizzaPrice.ToString();
            VS = radioButton1.Text;
            SummaryBox.Text = VS;
        }
        else
        {
            SummaryBox.Clear();
        }          
    }

    private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string SV;

        if (radioButton3.Enabled == true)                                   //PIZZA SPicy Veg
        {
            double svp = 5.20;
            PizzaPrice += svp;
            txtPizzaPrice.Text = "£ " + PizzaPrice.ToString();
            SV = radioButton3.Text;
            SummaryBox.Text = SV;
        }
        else
        {
            SummaryBox.Clear();  
        }
    }
    private void radioButton6_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MF;

        if (radioButton6.Enabled == true)                                 //PIZZA MEAT FEAST
        {
            double mfp = 5.80;
            PizzaPrice += mfp;
            txtPizzaPrice.Text = "£ " + PizzaPrice.ToString();
            MF = radioButton6.Text;
            SummaryBox.Text = MF;
        }
        else 
        {
            SummaryBox.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void radioButton7_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string HP;

        if (radioButton7.Enabled == true) //PIZZA Ham pineapple
        {
            double hpp = 4.20;
            PizzaPrice += hpp;
            txtPizzaPrice.Text = "£ " + PizzaPrice.ToString();
            HP = radioButton7.Text;
            SummaryBox.Text = HP;
        }
        else
        {
            SummaryBox.Clear();
        }
    }
    private void radioButton4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string SF;

        if (radioButton4.Enabled == true)                                       // PIZZA SEAFOOD
        {
            double sfp = 5.60;
            PizzaPrice += sfp;
            txtPizzaPrice.Text = "£ " + PizzaPrice.ToString();
            SF = radioButton4.Text;
            SummaryBox.Text = SF;
        }
        else
        {
            SummaryBox.Clear();
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bill sf = new Bill(); 
        sf.Show();                                                              // Open Bill
    }
    private void checkBox15_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                                                                           //EXTRA CHEESE
        string EC;

        if (checkBoxExtraCheese.Checked)
        {
            double ecp = .50;
            ExtraTopping += ecp;
            txtPizzaPrice.Text = "£ " + ExtraTopping.ToString();
            EC = checkBoxExtraCheese.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            ExtraTopping = 0 + PizzaPrice;
            txtPizzaPrice.Text = "£ " + ExtraTopping.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void checkBox10_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                                                                           //PEPPERS
        string PEP;

        if (checkBoxPeppers.Checked)
        {
            double pepp = .50;
            ExtraTopping += pepp;
            txtPizzaPrice.Text = "£ " + ExtraTopping.ToString();
            PEP = checkBoxPeppers.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            ExtraTopping = 0 + PizzaPrice;
            txtPizzaPrice.Text = "£ " + ExtraTopping.ToString();
        }
    }
    private void checkBoxCrispyOnions_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                                                                           //CRISPY ONIONS
        string CO;

        if (checkBoxCrispyOnions.Checked)
        {
            double cop = .50;
            ExtraTopping += cop;
            txtPizzaPrice.Text = "£ " + ExtraTopping.ToString();
            CO = checkBoxCrispyOnions.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            ExtraTopping = 0 + PizzaPrice;
            txtPizzaPrice.Text = "£ " + ExtraTopping.ToString();
        }
    }
    private void checkBoxGarlicSauce_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                                                                           //Garlic Sauce
        string GS;

        if (checkBoxGarlicSauce.Checked)
        {
            double gsp = .50;
            ExtraTopping += gsp;
            txtPizzaPrice.Text = "£ " + ExtraTopping.ToString();
            GS = checkBoxGarlicSauce.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            ExtraTopping = 0.0 + PizzaPrice;
            txtPizzaPrice.Text = "£ " + ExtraTopping.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void checkBoxPepperoni_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                                                                           //PEPPERONI
        string Proni;

        if (checkBoxPepperoni.Checked)
        {
            double pepperoni = .50;
            ExtraTopping += pepperoni;
            txtPizzaPrice.Text = "£ " + ExtraTopping.ToString();
            Proni = checkBoxPepperoni.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            ExtraTopping = 0 + PizzaPrice;
            txtPizzaPrice.Text = "£ " + ExtraTopping.ToString();
        }
    }
    private void rbThinandcrispy_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                                                                          //Add type of crust to summary box
        thincrispy = rbThinandcrispy.Text;
        SummaryBox.Text = thincrispy;
    }

    private void rbDeeppan_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                                                                           //Add type of crust to summary box
        Deeppan = rbDeeppan.Text;
        SummaryBox.Text = Deeppan;
    }

    Menu(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        clickCounter--;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is this your homework problem? Rather then copy pasting your whole code   ask specific question with specific code snippet.

Comment: Break your code sample down. There's really too much here to read...

Comment: Sorry, it involves all of the code, and no it is not homework, more like a project, I am new to C#, so would like some advice and help please.

Comment: This is incredibly hard to follow because the question and the code don't line up. You have a number of style issues that I won't go into but I'll point out the big things I see. You don't initialize most of your variables to anything. You create variables when they aren't needed (`double ctp = 3.50;PizzaPrice += ctp;` should be `PizzaPrice += 3.50`. You never subtract when something is unchecked. This could be related to why your amounts are off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fairly confusing, particularly because of controls with names like radioButton1, radioButton2, etc...

It looks like your issue could be stemming from the fact that when your pizza type radio buttons change state, you add the price of the newly selected pizza to the pizza price instead of replacing it.

I would strongly encourage you to adopt an object-oriented approach in your application. If you create a Pizza class with fields for extra toppings, each Pizza that you add to an order will know everything that should be on it and how much it costs in total, and the Pizza could have a .ToString() overload that would build the summary text you're looking for: i.e., "Supreme pizza (4.50) : cheese (.50), crispy onions (.50) = Total: 5.50"

Separating your business objects from the UI elements (checkboxes, radio buttons, text fields) will vastly simplify what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess but your add button only sets all your check boxes.Checked = false and then displays a popup.  It never actually adds the price of the current pizza selected to any totals.